# Как расширить список экспортированных настроек в phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Передо мной стала задача экспортировать настройки на другой компьютер, вот только не все настройки перенеслись. Например, горячие клавиши и плагины, которые я по-отключал, чтобы повысить производительность.
Вот мои настройки из filesettings.jar:
[image]
а вот те же настройки, которые я нашел в интернете у товарища, только он не отвечает на запрос(невооруженным глазом видно, что их больше):
[image]
Так как же быть с настройками, нужна помощь...

Comment: Это могут быть настройки дополнительных плагинов. Кроме того, есть вероятность, что настройки по умолчанию просто не экспортируются.

Comment: На личном опыте я понял, что встроенный экспорт работает каким-то чудным образом, поэтому пришёл к решению банальной подмены папки `~/.PhpStorm*/config` на другой машине.

Comment: А где находится файл config, у меня в директории с установленной программой нету его(windows 10)?

Comment: На Winwows не знаю, но на Linux в домашней директории (`~/`) в папке `PhpStorm<version>`.